# 2012 MacBook Air won't turn back on after removing Wi-Fi (AirPort) module

Tags: mac, hardware-failure, macbook-air

I wanted to take my 2012 MacBook Air off the grid completely, so I thought removing the Wi-Fi module would accomplish that.

I removed the AirPort module and tried to turn it on, but it wouldn't turn on. I put the module back in and tried to turn it on. Again, it wouldn't turn on. I tried [various tips to fix it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CB3o7kjPJI), but all failed.

Before removing the hardware, the Mac had a low power sign and technically the Mac was still on (I don't think the battery was completely dead since it had few cycles), and when I plug in the charger it turns green to red, but won't turn green again even though I left it plugged in overnight. Unplugging the battery and powering on the MacBook Air did not work either.

I smell a burnt smell near the AirPort module, but I'm not sure if it's the original hardware smell.

Has anybody had a similar issue and fixed it?

Comment: There's no way for us to know what you may have damaged or what cable you didn't reconnect correctly. Take it to a trained technician.

Comment: @Spiff Thanks for taking a look into my issue. I was hoping it's a software bug, which is triggered by a user removing the AirPort module. All plugs are correctly placed.

Comment: What did you do with the antenna leads that you disconnected from the module? Did you wrap them with non-conductive tape or tape them out of the way somewhere to make sure their metal connectors couldn't bump something else and short it out?

Comment: @Spiff I think you are right, I didn't do anything about the two antenna, that might have caused the short. Thanks, Spiff I will go to the local mac shops